# Django on Google cloud

Tags: database

I am new to both GKE and Django. I made an app in Django, made a docker container and push it to gcr and deploy it via GKE. The deployment works fine but when i try to login, I got the OperationalError. For database connection, I am using CloudSQL proxy.I have collected the static file and stored in google storage.  Any help will be highly appreciated.

I have tried quite many opinions available already online but failed to succeed.

When i try to login as admin, I got the following output after input my username and password for login.

OperationalError at /admin/login

server closed the connection unexpectedly 
This probably means the server terminated abnormally 
before or while processing the request.

Following are my database setting in Django.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'polls',
        'USER': os.getenv('DATABASE_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

[error while trying to login as admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhvrt.png)

Comment: The link "error while trying to login as admin" has a snapshot of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check in the docker logs , and check if there is any error connecting to the database

If it is a databse connection issue, then you can try the following in your docker-compose.yml . You can customize the rest of the variables mentioned, as needed for your **polls** application

you can try this

```
  web:
    build: ./app
    image: {imagename}
    depends_on:
     - cloud-sql-proxy
    environment:
      - SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2
      - SQL_DATABASE=test_db
      - SQL_USER=postgres1
      - SQL_PASSWORD=6728298
      - SQL_HOST=cloud-sql-proxy
      - SQL_PORT=5432
      - DATABASE=postgres

  cloud-sql-proxy:
    image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.11
    command: /cloud_sql_proxy -instances=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>=tcp:0.0.0.0:5432 -credential_file=/config
    volumes:
    - {service_account_creds_path.json}:/config
```

You could read this article https://adilsoncarvalho.com/how-to-use-cloud-sql-proxy-on-docker-compose-f7418c53eed9 for reference. The article is about mysql, but the concepts are the same . Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I finally figured out my error and it was due to improper dumping of the data from sqlite to postgresql.